# Gulp fails after VSO / VSTS upgrade

Tags: gulp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Since yesterday's update on VSO / VSTS ([17 Aug update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2016-aug-17-vso)) our gulp tasks fail.
The failing part is where we overwrite existing files using `gulp.dest()` in a gulp build step.

I've tried to delete the file first and then use `gulp.dest` and this works, however this practice can't be used on all places because we need to inject code into existing files.

We use Gulp version 3.9.0

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\a\1\s\Source\Project\Project.Web\index.cshtml'
```

Comment: What's the detail code? You can share a simple sample on OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last update of VSO all source files are now readonly. We solved our issue by removing the readonly flag on the source files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the issue is related to Gulp 3.9.0, I can reproduce that issue with Gulp 3.9.0 (npm install task, Command: install, Arguments: gulp@3.9.0), the Gulp 3.9.1 works fine. So you can update to gulp 3.9.1.

You could add npm install task to install latest version. (Command: install; Argument: gulp)